# How can I set a css ":hover" on a DOM created element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm using the DOM to manage a JSON response from an AJAX function I'm running. The script I'm writing needs to be completely portable, so I am defining the styles for the created elements on the fly (meaning, no linking to an external CSS, and no providing CSS in the HTML doc itself, because I won't have control of the doc).

I'd like to create a hover effect on some of the elements.

example:

```
 #myDiv:hover { background:#000000; }
```

Is there a way to define that in the DOM?  Or do I have to use `mouseover`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can dynamically create and manipulate stylesheets. [See here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#change) for some of the cross-browser issues with this approach.

I've got a wrapper function [lying around](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/createstylesheet.js) which works around some of them; using it, the code would read

```
document.createStyleSheet().addRule('#myDiv:hover', 'background:#000000;');
```

Comment: For me inline CSS isn't good enough. I mean good answer, so I'm not downvoting but it should be possible another way.

Comment: 2017 update: createStyleSheet() was IE only, but from IE11 deprecated https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ms531194(v=vs.71)

Answer (score 3):

you may create element with predefined class:

```
.h:hover{color: #c00}

var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.className = 'h'
```

Comment: good, and yes...however i didn't have the ability to link to a stylesheet