# How can I change the style of the document via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

That would go like this *** {margin:0; padding:0;}**  in CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the (first) stylesheet object use

```
document.styleSheets[0]
```

To access the (first) rule in the stylesheet use on of:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0] // firefox
document.styleSheets[0].rules[0]    // IE
```

You can add rules with

```
insertRule(rule, index)                 // firefox
addRule(selector, declaration, [index]) // IE
```

Thus, to do what you describe in firefox:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("*{margin:0; padding:0;}", 0)
```

And to do it in IE:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule("*", "margin:0; padding:0;", 0)
```

See also: [Dom StyleSheet Object](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714655/how-can-i-set-a-css-hover-on-a-dom-created-element-in-javascript/714717#714717 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript/524721#524721 for two different approaches on dynamically creating the stylesheet if you don't want to append to an existing one

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to change the padding and margin for the body element:

```
document.body.setAttribute('padding', '0');
document.body.setAttribute('margin', '0');
```

Comment: This would only set the styles on the body, the question is to set the styles on everything - *

Comment: Actually I want to change the cursor type for the whole document (not only within the body).