# Javascript: Set an elements color on hover through .style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writting CSS dynamically in Javascript. I am trying to specify(in Javscript) that when the mouse hovers over a paragraph element its text colour changes.

**Is there a way to do this without having to resort to the onMouseOver way, something like...**

```
myEle.style.colorHover = "#FFFFFF";

// Maybe this works?
var ele = document.createElement("p");
ele.style.colorHover = "#FFFFFF";
ele.style.backgroundColorHover = "#000000";
ele.style.color = "#000000";
ele.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714655/how-can-i-set-a-css-hover-on-a-dom-created-element-in-javascript - it's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Given the lack of support for the *hover* pseudo-class in IE, hover effects are usually implemented using listeners for mouseover/out events on a parent element (e.g. on a tbody or table element for table rows).

Comment: If you are doing this to more than 1 elemnt on the page, i'd recommend using jQuery and the hover() handler http://api.jquery.com/hover/ makes it s a little nicer to manage IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your text in an additional A tag and use :hover to change the color of your text.

Of course you'll probably want to create a class and add it via JavaScript.

JavaScript:

```
ele.setAttribute("class", "myClass");
```

CSS:

```
P A.myClass
{
 /* colors when not hovering */   
}
P A.myClass:hover
{
 /* colors when hovering */
}
```